# C++ error code: std::bad_alloc at memory location

Tags: c++

I am using Visual studio now and I have a question about an error message that I got.

It says 'std::bad_alloc at memory location'.

I guess this means that I don't have enough memory. I am using arrays for computation and I think the problem arises from the size of each array.

First I used stack instead of heap so I allocate every array dynamically. But still, I got the same error message.

If I reduce the size of the array, I could run this code but I need to use this with a bigger size of arrays.

If I use a better computer, can I run this code? I am not sure how to reduce the memory required to run this code.... should I use fewer arrays?

Below, I put the entire code just in case....

Thanks in advance.

```
include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>       // power
#include <cmath>        // abs
#include <fstream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

// Dynamically allocation with values(double)
void dallo_fn(double**** pMat, int Na, int Nd, int Ny) {
    double*** Mat = new double** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Mat[i] = new double* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Mat[i][j] = new double[Ny];
            fill_n(Mat[i][j], Ny, 1);
        }
    }
    *pMat = Mat;
}

// Dynamically allocation without values(double)
void dallo_fn0(double**** pMat, int Na, int Nd, int Ny) {
    double*** Mat = new double** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Mat[i] = new double* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Mat[i][j] = new double[Ny];
        }
    }
    *pMat = Mat;
}

// Dynamically allocation without values(int)
void dallo_fn1(int**** pMat, int Na, int Nd, int Ny) {
    int*** Mat = new int** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Mat[i] = new int* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Mat[i][j] = new int[Ny];
        }
    }
    *pMat = Mat;
}

// Utility function
double utility(double a, double a_f, double d, double d_f, double y, double sig, double psi, double delta, double R) {
    double C;
    C = y + a - a_f / R - (d_f - (1 - delta) * d);
    double result;
    if (C > 0) {
        result = 1 / (1 - 1 / sig) * pow(pow(C, psi) * pow(d_f, 1 - psi), (1 - 1 / sig));
    }
    else {
        result = -999999;
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
#if defined _OPENMP
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
#endif

    double duration;

    // Iteration Parameters
    double tol = 0.000001;
    double itmax = 200;
    double H = 15;

    // Model Parameters and utility function
    double sig = 0.75;
    double beta = 0.95;
    double psi = 0.5;
    double delta = 0.1;
    double R = 1 / beta - 0.00215;

    // =============== 2. Discretizing the state space =========================

    // Size of arrays
    const int Na = 2 * 91;
    const int Nd = 1 * 71;
    const int Ny = 3;

    // Variables for discretization of state space
    const double amin = -2;
    const double amax = 7;
    const double dmin = 0.01;
    const double dmax = 7;
    const double ymin = 0.5;
    const double ymax = 1.5;
    const double Ptrans[3] = { 0.2, 0.6, 0.2 };

    // Discretization of state space
    double ca = (amax - amin) / (Na - 1.0);
    double cd = (dmax - dmin) / (Nd - 1.0);
    double cy = (ymax - ymin) / (Ny - 1.0);

    double* A = new double[Na];
    double* Y = new double[Ny];
    double* D = new double[Nd];

    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        A[i] = amin + i * ca;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Nd; i++) {
        D[i] = dmin + i * cd;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Ny; i++) {
        Y[i] = ymin + i * cy;
    }

    // === 3. Initial guesses, Variable initialization and Transition matrix ===

    // Initial guess for value function
    double*** V;
    dallo_fn(&V, Na, Nd, Ny);
    double*** Vnew;
    dallo_fn(&Vnew, Na, Nd, Ny);

    // Initialization of other variables
    double Val[Na][Nd];
    double Vfuture[Na][Nd];
    double** temphoward = new double* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        temphoward[i] = new double[Nd];
    }
    
    double*** Vhoward;
    dallo_fn0(&Vhoward, Na, Nd, Ny);
    double*** tempdiff;
    dallo_fn0(&tempdiff, Na, Nd, Ny);
    int*** maxposition_a;
    dallo_fn1(&maxposition_a, Na, Nd, Ny);
    int*** maxposition_d;
    dallo_fn1(&maxposition_d, Na, Nd, Ny);

    double** mg_A_v = new double* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        mg_A_v[i] = new double[Nd];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            mg_A_v[i][j] = A[i];
        }
    }

    double** mg_D_v = new double* [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++)
    {
        mg_D_v[i] = new double[Nd];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            mg_D_v[i][j] = D[j];
        }
    }

    double***** Uvec = new double**** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        Uvec[i] = new double*** [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            Uvec[i][j] = new double** [Ny];
            for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                Uvec[i][j][k] = new double* [Na];
                for (int l = 0; l < Na; l++) {
                    Uvec[i][j][k][l] = new double[Nd];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < Na; l++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < Nd; m++) {
                        Uvec[i][j][k][l][m] = utility(A[i], mg_A_v[l][m], D[j], mg_D_v[l][m], Y[k], sig, psi, delta, R);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Value function iteration
    int it;
    double dif;
    double max;
    it = 0;
    dif = 1;

    // ================ 4. Value function iteration ============================

    while (dif >= tol && it <= itmax) {
        system_clock::time_point start = system_clock::now();
        it = it + 1;
        // V = Vnew;
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    V[i][j][k] = Vnew[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                Vfuture[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    Vfuture[i][j] += beta * Ptrans[k] * Vnew[i][j][k]; // + beta * Ptrans[1] * Vnew[i][j][1] + beta * Ptrans[2] * Vnew[i][j][2]; // Why is this different from Vfuture[i][j] += beta * Vnew[i][j][k] * Ptrans[k]; with for k
                }
            }
        }
        #pragma omp parallel for private(Val)     
        for (int a = 0; a < Na; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < Nd; b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < Ny; c++) {
                    max = -99999;
                    for (int d = 0; d < Na; d++) {
                        for (int e = 0; e < Nd; e++) {
                            Val[d][e] = Uvec[a][b][c][d][e] + Vfuture[d][e];
                            if (max < Val[d][e]) {
                                max = Val[d][e];
                                maxposition_a[a][b][c] = d;
                                maxposition_d[a][b][c] = e;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Vnew[a][b][c] = max;
                }
            }
        }

        // Howard improvement
        for (int h = 0; h < H; h++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                        Vhoward[i][j][k] = Vnew[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                        temphoward[i][j] = beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][0] * Ptrans[0]
                            + beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][1] * Ptrans[1]
                            + beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][2] * Ptrans[2];
                        Vnew[i][j][k] = temphoward[i][j] + Uvec[i][j][k][maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // Calculate Diff
        dif = -100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    tempdiff[i][j][k] = abs(V[i][j][k] - Vnew[i][j][k]);
                    if (tempdiff[i][j][k] > dif) {
                        dif = tempdiff[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        system_clock::time_point end = system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> sec = end - start;


        cout << dif << endl;
        cout << it << endl;
        cout << sec.count() << endl;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                cout << Vnew[i][j][k];
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    cout << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;

}
```

Comment: I've just witnessed four star programming.

Comment: Note the array of arrays approach to multi-dimensional arrays can get very cache-unfriendly and thus very slow. Often better to make a big 1D array and do the math to make it look multidimensional.

Comment: If you multiply up the size of your largest n-dimensional array how many bytes do you get (remember on 64-bit pointers are 8 bytes) ?

Comment: Maybe it is just the huge fragmentation caused by the excessive amount of tiny allocations. Allocate your fields in big arrays and index by integer arithmetic offsets. Or better: Use a appropriate library which already implements this.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Your problem begins in the portion code of building the Uvec vector. Using that dimentions you're trying to allocate a 5-dimension matrix with 500,934,252 elements. It's a huuuuuuuuge matrix

Comment: @robbinc91: I have 16GB of RAM and I guess this is too small....

Comment: @ChangseokMa building for 64-bit ?

Comment: @Richard Critten: Yes building for 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with enough memory you can run this code. I've tested it just now on my machine with 64GBs of RAM and it ran just fine.

One way to reduce the amount of memory required is to use `float`s instead of `double`s, as they take up half the size.

Moreover, as others suggested in the comments already you could represent the multidimensional structures as 1d arrays and compute the indices into the array instead of actually having nested arrays. The benefit is that you get rid of a huge number of pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I want to maintain these multidimensional structures rather than using vectorized(1d) version. Does that mean the only way to do this is to use a machine with a bigger size of RAM?

Comment: @ChangseokMa It just checked, it uses slightly more than 4GB on my machine. So maybe you only need to close enough other memory hungry applications to be able to run it on your machine. Or you replace all `double`s with `float`s as I suggested, then it only uses 2.2GB of memory.

Comment: Thanks. When we calculate the size of the required memory, can I just multiply 8 by the size of each array and then sum them up?

Comment: @ChangseokMa When you use doubles then yes because doubles and pointers both take up 8 bytes. If you use floats then you need to make sure you multiply by 8 for all pointers you store and only by 4 for the arrays that store the actual values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. The thing is I am only using 6.7GB out of 16GB of my ram but somehow I cannot run it. It also says that the function uses 52072 bytes of stack. And I guess my size is 16384. I guess there is nothing to allocate dynamically anymore so I just changed 'Stack Reserve Size' as 60000. Would this matter? Or maybe I think I should try with a different machine.

Comment: @ChangseokMa: std::bad_alloc doesn't get thrown on stack allocation failure, so your stack size is fine. Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am running Windows with Visual studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229481/discussion-between-corristo-and-changseok-ma).

Answer (score 0):

The code is admittedly pretty memory hungry, but works on my 8GB machine. Please make sure you are targetting x64 platform, otherwise you reach the 4GB inherent limit.